# Fading pages in web application developer c#

Tags: c#, javascript, fade, visual-web-developer-2010

I read many posts about how to add the function of fading page but I have some problems.
It is not clear to me the code to type in the jquery.js and hot to connect this script page to all my web forms of alternatively to the master page to which all my web forms are connected.

Anyone can help?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Adding jQuery to your page, creating a JavaScript script file and adding that to your page(s), or the mechanics of using jQuery to fade elements?

Comment: please help me I am loooost! :(

Comment: What **exactly** is it you are lost with? 1) Do know what jQuery is and how to add it to your project? 2) Do you know how to add jQuery to a page or Masterpage? 3) Do you know what JavaScript is? 4) Do you know how to create a new script or script file? 5) Do you know how to attach the script file you have created to your page or Masterpage? 6) Do you understand from the tutorials you have read how to use jQuery to fade elements.

Comment: I just realised what a crappy question I asked back then. I was not even a developer. I apologise to the community for the poor content and the unhelpful attitude. 
Things changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, this question is far beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question (which focus on a single programming problem or issue) - you will find that time spent learning about **JavaScript** (a client side programming language) and **jQuery** (a JavaScript *framework* which provides a simple single API to abstract away from differences in browser implementations and makes it easier to work with elements in web pages) is extremely well spent, and really a pre-cursor to what you are trying to achieve. Obviously you will not need to become an expert before you can work with it, but you will need to spend a couple of hours on the basics.

In essence, what you will need to do is download (either via [NuGet](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/overview) or from the [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/)) a copy of the jQuery library, add this to your page or MasterPage, and **then** either create an inline script or add a script file (after you have added jQuery) that uses it to achieve the effect you are after. I **strongly** suggest you look at the **free** [Try jQuery course from CodeSchool](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-jquery), and read the articles at the [jQuery Learning Centre](http://learn.jquery.com/). These should between them give you enough knowledge to do what you want to achieve.

As an extension to this I'd suggest also taking the (again free) [JavaScript Road Trip Part 1](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/javascript-road-trip-part-1) to give you some knowledge of the absolute basics of JavaScript, and there are also some great free courses at [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript). These may be something you do in the slack time after you have solved your initial problem.

Whilst you are solving your problem, there is great documentation available on the various methods and functions available within jQuery in their [core API documentation area](http://api.jquery.com/), and on JavaScript at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) (which applies to other browsers as well as Firefox). In particular you will want to look at [selecting elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/), the [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) methods. At a minimum look through the introductory sections on the [jQuery learning centre](http://learn.jquery.com/) **first** though, as this will save you a lot of grief later on.

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, please "Accept" the answer  by clicking on the "tick" icon next to the answer. If you require more information please update the question or add comments. Thanks.